# creating an array, read a file and creating a new file - java

Tags: java, file, class, text-files

Suppose you are given a text file “students.txt” that contains the data of students. Every line in the file is composed by the first name, the last name, the score of the test1, the score of the test2 and the grade of the final.  The different fields of a line are separated by “:”. The first line of the student contains the number of lines (students).

Create a class Student composed that contains the following attributes:

First_Name

Last_Name

Grade_Test1

Grade_Test2

Grade_Final

Total_Score

Additionally, the class student contains :

-A constructor defined with 4 parameters to initialize, the first name, the last name, Grade Test1 and Grade test1 of a new object of type student.

-A method to calculate the total score with the following formula : Test1*0.2+Test2*0.2+Final*0.6

-6 accessors  methods respectively for each  attributes.

Write a Java program :

-Create an array of type student.

-Read the file and fill the array of students (you should compute the total score for each student).

-Create a new file named “Result.txt”. Write in this file the list of success students (Total score >=60). Each line should contain the first name, last name and the total score of each student.  Write also the average of the total score of all the students.

i've been struggling solving this question, I'm not that good at programming tho

```
public class Student{
private String FirstName;
private String LastName;
private double Test1;
private double Test2;
private double Final;
private double TotalScore;
public Student(String f, String l, double t1, double t2){
    FirstName = f;
    LastName = l;
    Test1 = t1;
    Test2 = t2;
}
public void CalculateTotal(){
    TotalScore = Test1*0.2 + Test2*0.2 + Final*0.6;
}
public String getFirstName(){
    return FirstName;
}
public String getLastName(){
    return LastName;
}
public double getTest1(){
    return Test1;
}
public double getTest2(){
    return Test2;
}
public double getFinal(){
    return Final;
}
public double getTotalScore(){
    return TotalScore;
}
```

}

```
public class AppStudent {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Student [] array;
    String fileName = "students.txt";
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
        String line = inputStream.next();
        String ary[]= line.split(" : ");
        //heres where I'm struggling
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Struggling with what? What's going wrong with your attempts, specifically?

Comment: you have just given a list of requirements. this is not the proper way to use Stack Overflow! read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center

Comment: This is like a homework question you want to solve

Comment: it is a homework. i edited it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

> The different fields of a line are separated by “:”

so your code should be

```
String ary[]= line.split(":");
```

Now assuming that the field match the order of the `Student` constructor

```
public Student(String f, String l, double t1, double t2)
```

you can create a `Student` as

```
Student std = new Student (arr[0], arr[1], 
                          Double.valueof (arr[2]), Double.valueOf (arr[3]));
```

This new `Student` object can then be added to you Array of students

> -Create an array of type student.